# Converting time stamp in powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I get the below time stamp from API response how do i convert this to human readable text in power shell, i tried below but it is throwing error.

```
PS C:\Users\foobar\ddd> [datetime]::ParseExact('20100804T104413+0100','
yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzz',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
At line:1 char:57
+ [datetime]::ParseExact('20100804T104413+0100','yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzz', ...
+                                                         ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:57
+ ... me]::ParseExact('20100804T104413+0100','yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzz',[System ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'T'HHmmsszzz'' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:69
+ ... e]::ParseExact('20100804T104413+0100','yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzz',[System. ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:122
+ ... dd'T'HHmmsszzz',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

> 20170125T153341-050020170125T153344-0500

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only problem seems to be the errant (lack of) quoting of `T` in your code; removing it seems to work fine:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact('20100804T104413+0100','yyyyMMddTHHmmsszzz', $null)
```

Also, since you're providing a format string in which all characters are specified individually and numerically, you needn't specify a culture (passing `$null`, which defaults to the current culture, will do).